# Uninstall the debugging mode from a device

Tags: java, android, adb

I need to generate my system to lunch my app that I developed .
to more secure and  guaranteed my system ,i **need to block all things which they can  uninstall my launcher my question here is** :
**how can I uninstall the debugging mode from my device** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building a new system you can remove adb but would not recommend doing that.
You would remove a big feature without any gain. If you really want your app to be impossible to uninstall just make it a system app, root users would be able to remove it but that is why they root their devices. Now how to remove adb, from what i know adb is not a java app but a linux binary. That binary is a adb demon that listens for connections. If you delete it nothing will listen for connections and adb is removed. Beware that you may cause unexpected error in the system this way! This is all i could find out and for location of binary you will have to do some more research.

Comment: i install an open source kernel and i changed some script file to get my goal

Answer (score 0):

I it is not possible in any way on a phone that is not rooted. For rooted phones i am not sure but i believe it is almost impossible. For something like that you would have to make your own android version and completely remove any debugging options, while being very careful not to break anything else.

If for some reason you don't want your app to be launched while usb debugging is enabled you can use

```
`Setting.Global.ADB_ENABLED`
```

to check if adb is enabled or not on launch and close your app if it is.

Comment: Hi i have a device that bocked the debugging mode in a way when i click 7 times in the seriel build the debugging mode was not opened . and that what i want

Comment: For that you will have to make a new system with debugging removed. Why would you want to block debugging anyway?

Answer (score -1):

Just go into the phones settings 
Developer options > USB debugging > off

Comment: endly the user can open the degugging mode and use adb to uninstall my application not this the solution friend .

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to uninstall debugging mode since it's built into the OS.

Comment: This will disable the debugging mode, not uninstall it

Comment: i have a device that bocked the debugging mode in a way when i click 7 times in the seriel build the debugging mode was not opened .